# OpenFOAM: FOAM FATAL ERROR: Unknown TurbulenceModel type RASModel

Tags: openfoam

I'm trying to follow [this OpenFOAM tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MUGnlYncqck) for using Gmsh to generate Axisymmetric mesh. The files are provided [here](https://github.com/openfoamtutorials/OpenFOAM_Tutorials_/tree/master/Axisymmetric2D). However when I try to solve the problem using the `pimpleFoam` solver I get the error:

> --> FOAM FATAL ERROR:
>   Unknown TurbulenceModel type RASModel
>
> Valid TurbulenceModel types:
>
> 3
>   (
>   LES
>   RAS
>   laminar
>   )
>
> From function static Foam::autoPtr > Foam::TurbulenceModel::New(const alphaField&, const rhoField&, const volVecto rField&, const surfaceScalarField&, const surfaceScalarField&, const transportMo del&, const Foam::word&) [with Alpha = Foam::geometricOneField; Rho = Foam::geom etricOneField; BasicTurbulenceModel = Foam::incompressibleTurbulenceModel; Trans portModel = Foam::transportModel; Foam::TurbulenceModel::alphaField = Foam::geometricOneField; Foam::Turbulenc eModel::rhoField = Foam::geome tricOneField; Foam::volVectorField = Foam::GeometricField; Foam::surfaceScalarField = Foam::GeometricFi eld; Foam::TurbulenceModel::transportModel = Foam::transportMo del]
>   in file /opt/CFDSupportFOAM4.0/beta/OpenFOAM-dev/src/TurbulenceModels/turbul enceModels/lnInclude/TurbulenceModel.C at line 113.﻿

As explained in [this page](https://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/openfoam-solving/165811-unknown-turbulence-model-type-rasmodel.html) apparently the syntax of `turbulenceProperties` in `case/constant` has changed. So I edited the `turbulenceProperties` file from:

`simulationType RASModel;`

to

```
simulationType RAS;

RAS
{
RASModel kEpsilon;

turbulence      on;

printCoeffs     on;
}
```

but then I get a different error:

> FOAM FATAL IO ERROR:
>   attempt to read beyond EOF
>
> file: .../Axisymmetric2D/case/system/fvSchemes.divSchemes.default at line 29.
>
> From function virtual Foam::Istream& Foam::ITstream::read(Foam::token&)
>   in file db/IOstreams/Tstreams/ITstream.C at line 82.
>   FOAM exiting

It seems like the tutorial is meant for an older version of OpenFOAM. I would appreciate if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can solve it.

The goal for me is to learn how to make axisymmetric mesh using Gmsh. so out of the box solutions or tutorials for the newer versions of OpenFOAM als would do.

P.S. I have reported the issue [here in the Github repo](https://github.com/openfoamtutorials/OpenFOAM_Tutorials_/issues/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by looking into the different versions of `axisymmetricJet` template provided in [official OpenFOAM GitHub repo](https://github.com/OpenFOAM) ([version 2.3.x](https://github.com/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.x/tree/master/etc/templates/axisymmetricJet) and [version 5.x](https://github.com/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-dev/tree/master/etc/templates/axisymmetricJet)). Changes to be made:

1. in `case/constant/RASProperties` add these at the end:

```
kEpsilonCoeffs
{
    Cmu 0.09;
    C1 1.44;
    C2 1.92;
    sigmaEps 1.3;
}
```

2. in `case/constant/turbulenceProperties` replace the line `simulationType  RASModel;` with:

```
simulationType RAS;

RAS
{

        RASModel            kEpsilon;

        turbulence          on;
        printCoeffs         on;
}
```

3. in `case/system/fvSchemes` change the line `div((nuEff*dev(T(grad(U))))) Gauss linear;` to `div((nuEff*dev2(T(grad(U))))) Gauss linear;`

It the solver converges as expected. I still don't know what these changes mean and how they work. I will add them as soon as I figure that out. I have forked [the GitHub repo here](https://github.com/Foadsf/OpenFOAM_Tutorials_/tree/master/Axisymmetric2D) including the required edits.